# Soundcloud Api - get track by singer

Tags: javascript, php, soundcloud

Hi please I would like to create the same thing [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rihanna%20%2C) at audio section, so when I type a name of a singer It will send me a Json data of that singer with all available tracks in soundcloud website throught its API.

This is the code i'm trying right now:

```
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script>
        SC.initialize({
          client_id: 'Client_ID'
        });

        // stream track id 293
        SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
          sound.play();
        });
    </script>
```

So as you can see the track ID is simple to get it from soundcloud API from this link: `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`

but what I want is getting these IDs of a specific singer passed as parameter to a function, all with Javascript please else with PHP.

Comment: So no one can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hit `/users` endpoint with `q` param in order to try to match the artist name:

```
SC.get('/users', {q: 'rihanna'}, function (users) {
  console.log(users);
  // iterate over users, do the matching
  // hit the users api link, get tracks and stream them via their IDs
});
```

View the example here – http://jsbin.com/xugomagami/1/edit?html,js,console,output